# Can't install Netis WF2123 drivers for Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, 20.04

I'm a new Ubuntu user on the version 20.04.3 LTS. My laptop doesn't have a buit-in wireless card, so I'm using the Netis WF2123 USB card. When I try to install the drivers, following the instructions of the manufacturer, I get the following error:

https://pastebin.com/EaPawkMm

I have tried adding some user tags to the Makefile file, as some other post suggested, but it wouldn't do anything, and after running the `sudo sh install.sh` command, it would revert back to the file version without the flags. If you need any additional info, I can provide it, but please give me specific instructions, I'm a new Linux user. Thank you.

Comment: You can find how to install drivers for this dongle. Search by "rtl8192eu". That driver is too old.

Comment: @Pilot6 hey, so I found [this](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver) on github, but it requires to install DKMS, which requires internet connection, but the laptop doesn't have an ethernet port, and the dongle isn't working yet. Is there any way to download DKMS on a windows pc, place it on the laptop trough a pendrive, and install it that way?

Comment: Why don't you use a temporary USB tethered connection from your phone? Any modern smartphone will do.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thats actually really clever, didnt think of that. Ill try and get back to you.

Comment: I installed [the driver](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver), following the README guide, and it's still not working. I have no clue why, the device is detected, but not as a wireless card.

Comment: Maybe you didn't really install it, or it is a wrong driver.